# Historical sum for current group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database with people, from which I want to see how much experience each person has in a specific department.

In the current query I have the following code:

```
SELECT [PERSON_ID]
,sum(case when [DEPARTMENT] = 'Marketing' then 1 else 0 end) as Exp_Marketing
,sum(case when [FUNCTION_DESC] = 'Finance' then 1 else 0 end) as Exp_Finance
FROM [xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxx]
GROUP BY [PERSON_ID]
```

Each person has one row for the months of service, so a person with 12 months of experience in Finance has a value of 12 in the Exp_Finance column.

The issue however is that the result now shows the outcome for all people. Also the one who already left the organization. How can I make sure the result only shows the historical information for the people currently part in the organization. In other words, the ones actually having a row with "2018M06" as value for the Date column.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful. Also tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT [PERSON_ID],
      sum(case when [DEPARTMENT] = 'Marketing' then 1 else 0 end) as Exp_Marketing,
      sum(case when [FUNCTION_DESC] = 'Finance' then 1 else 0 end) as Exp_Finance
FROM [xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxx]
GROUP BY [PERSON_ID]
HAVING MAX([DATE]) = '2018M06';
```

Your month format seems amenable to using `MAX()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `EXISTS` within a `WHERE` clause so you only include people meeting your criteria.

```
SELECT [PERSON_ID]
,sum(case when [DEPARTMENT] = 'Marketing' then 1 else 0 end) as Exp_Marketing
,sum(case when [FUNCTION_DESC] = 'Finance' then 1 else 0 end) as Exp_Finance
FROM [xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxx] A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxx] B
   WHERE A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID AND B.[DATE] = '2018M06')
GROUP BY [PERSON_ID]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason! I tried the solution Gordon Linoff suggested, which solved the problem. Appreciate your support!